# How to change font color of disabled TextField Material UI React js

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, react-with-styles

I'm trying to change disabled TextField font color and I followed related questions about it in stackoverflow but when I create a new TextField like below it does not work and shows nothing.

```js
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";


const myTextField = withStyles({
root: {
"& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled": {
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.0)"
}
}
})(TextField);


             

                                        <myTextField
                                            value={user  != null ? user.nam : null}
                                            disabled={true}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            margin="normal"
                                            fullWidth
                                            id="nam"
                                            autoFocus
                                            label="nam"
                                        />



                                        <TextField
                                            value={user  != null ? user.famil : null}
                                            disabled={true}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            margin="normal"
                                            fullWidth
                                            id="famil"
                                            autoFocus
                                            label="famil"
                                        />
```

[It shows the TextField "famil" but doesn't show myTextField "nam"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxnDS.png)

Comment: Note that reactjs.org recommends having you component with upper cased 1st letter. Update "myTextField" to "MyTextField" and see what happens.

Comment: Ey Vallah , It is work . Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

My muistake was I use lowerCase name for React Component .
I update "myTextField" to "MyTextField" and it works.

Another thing that you must use  .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-disabled class
to change font color.
.MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled class just change lable font color of TextField.

```js
const MyTextField = withStyles({
root: {
"& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-disabled": {
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.0)"
},
"& .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-disabled": {
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.0)"
},

}
})(TextField);
```